Storing logs in a file (flutter)
I am using the package logger. I want to write all the logs printed in the console to a separate file(in release mode too). I want to be able to download this file at anytime from the app. How do I do it?

https://pub.dev/documentation/logger/latest/logger/LogOutput-class.html

@pskink Can you share an example/code snippet, how we can use this?

here https://pub.dev/documentation/logger/latest/logger/Logger/Logger.html you can pass output: ... with any LogOutput you want

The logs are not being logged in the file path that I have provided for some reason. If the file doesn't exist, it is being created but no logs are being written to it.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Create a logger instance
  final Logger logger = Logger();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    logger.d('Debug message');
    logger.i('Info message');
    logger.w('Warning message');
    logger.e('Error message');

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Logger Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Check the log file for messages'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


final logger = Logger(
  printer: PrettyPrinter(
    methodCount: 0,
    errorMethodCount: 8,
    lineLength: 120,
    colors: true,
    printEmojis: true,
    printTime: false,
  ),
  output: MultiOutput([
    ConsoleOutput(),
    FileOutput(),
  ]),
);


The logs are not being logged in the file path that I have provided for some reason.
Is creating a logger instance necessary? Can't the one defined with printer and output parameters suffice?
